# Azure Pipelines: Recursive file pattern produces 0 matches when searching for existing file

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Our pipeline includes the following task:

```
- task: RegexReplace@3
  displayName: "Replace token on $(resourceName)"
  condition: eq(variables['Agent.MachineName'], variables['TargetMachine'])
  inputs:
    inputSearchPattern: '**\*tokenized.config'
    findRegex: '\${ReplaceMe}'
    replaceRegex: 'Tokenization replacement successful'
    useUTF8: false
    useRAW: true
```

The condition works just fine. But when we get to the part where it's trying find matching files, the build log always reports the following:

> Starting: Replace token on MYTARGETSERVER
>
> =========================================================================
>
> Task         : RegEx Find & Replace
>
> Description  : Find & Replace using Regular Expressions
>
> Version      : 3.3.11
>
> Author       : knom
>
> Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/knom/vsts-regex-tasks/)
>
> =========================================================================
>
> Search Pattern is **\*tokenized.config
>
> **Found 0 files**
>
> Replacing ${ReplaceMe} with Tokenization replacement successful (ASCII, RAW)
>
> Finishing: Replace token on MYTARGETSERVER

As shown, 0 files were matched, so our replacements don't occur. This happens no matter how we adjust the recursive file pattern.

We have tried:

- `**/*.tokenized.config`
- `**\*.tokenized.config`
- `**/*tokenized.config`
- `**\*tokenized.config`
- `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.tokenized.config`

My understanding is that the first pattern above should work and find our `project.tokenized.config` file. The file structure is as follows:

- Solution Folder

  - Project Folder

    - `Project.tokenized.config`

**What are we doing wrong in specifying the file pattern? Why doesn't recursive search seem to work here, producing 0 matches?**

Note that we use the `RegexReplace` task because we want to modify specific settings on a per-server basis within our production environment. To our knowledge, the `ReplaceTokens` task doesn't support that.

**ADDENDUM**

The following tasks are further down in the same file, and they execute exactly as we expect them to, using the same file patterns.

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: "Replace tokens in tokenized configuration files"
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: "$(sitePath)"
    targetFiles: |
      **/*.tokenized.config => *.config
      **/*.tokenized.js => *.js
      **/*.tokenized.json => *.json
    encoding: "auto"
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: "warn"
    keepToken: true
    tokenPrefix: "${"
    tokenSuffix: "}"
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: false

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: "Remove tokenized files"
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(sitePath)
    contents: |
      **/*.tokenized.config
      **/*.tokenized.js
      **/*.tokenized.json
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file pattern you're searching for actually exists when the task is run?

Comment: Yes. It definitely does. The `ReplaceTokens` task later in the pipeline successfully replaces tokens in the file.

Comment: Is "later in the pipeline" *within the same job*, or a different job? Post your entire pipeline, please.

Comment: It's within the same job. As for posting the entire pipeline, that would be tricky as we have YAML templates that call YAML templates that call YAML templates. However, the relevant portions are merely lines apart from one another within the same template. I could provide that part if it's helpful. (More than that would potentially pose a problem with regards to revealing confidential/proprietary information.)

Comment: @DanielMann I've added the YML for the two tasks that work using the same variables and patterns.

Comment: Is it something to do with the file location perhaps? The other two tasks both have a parameter for the search location, your `$(sitePath)` , but the RegexReplace@3 doesn't have such a parameter; and I'm not sure, from the task docs, exactly where it searches.

Comment: @VinceBowdren We thought so, as well. However, we tried setting the path to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.tokenized.config`, which works in a different pipeline, and still got zero matches. It hasn't occurred to me to try `$(sitePath)`, for some reason. I'll give that a shot.